# LFS Troubles - Applying Patch in Section 5.7.1

Tags: patch, syntax

Apologize in advance if this has been asked before, and if it is very obvious. I'm following the guide pretty literally at this point to get started. The page in question is this:

http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/glibc.html

This point specifies to run this:

```
patch -Np1 -i ../glibc-2.22-upstream_i386_fix-1.patch
```

However, doing so seems to return this:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 20
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Submitted By:            Bruce Dubbs <bdubbs at linuxfromscratch dot org>
|Date:                    2015-08-23
|Initial Package Version: 2.22
|Upstream Status:         In repository
|Origin:                  https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc
|Description:             This patch fixes a build problem on 32-bit systems.
|
|commit a08e80d1143f6b0386d5bc8cc7b8ed576091dbf3
|Author: Andrew Senkevich <andrew.senkevich@intel.com>
|Date:   Wed Aug 19 16:54:28 2015 +0300
|
|        [BZ #18796]
|        * scripts/test-installation.pl: Don't add -lmvec to build options if
|        libmvec wasn't built.
|
|diff --git a/scripts/test-installation.pl b/scripts/test-installation.pl
|index cac1562..79b2b3e 100755
|--- a/scripts/test-installation.pl
|+++ b/scripts/test-installation.pl
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

So for starters, for those of you who have followed the guide before, where exactly should the patch be in relation to the file it is patching? What file IS it patching in particular? And what directory should I be in when running this command?

For reference, I have created the directories /mnt/lfs /mnt/lfs/sources /mnt/lfs/tools as asked in the guide.

Source files and patches look like they were supposed to go in lfs/sources, and extracted files into lfs/tools. So currently the patch is in /mnt/lfs/sources and the extracted files for glibc-2.22 are in /mnt/lfs/tools

```
lfs@linux-NVIDIA-nForce-590-SLI /mnt/lfs $ ls -lah /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.22-upstream_i368_fix-1.patch 
-rw-r--r-- 1 linux linux 1.9K Sep 30 20:23 /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.22-upstream_i368_fix-1.patch

lfs@linux-NVIDIA-nForce-590-SLI /mnt/lfs $ ls -lah /mnt/lfs/tools/glibc-2.22 -ddrwxr-xr-x 68 lfs lfs 4.0K Aug  5 01:42 /mnt/lfs/tools/glibc-2.22
```

If I'm leaving anything out, please let me know, I'm just beating my head against the wall trying to understand this patch point.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so LFS is off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/generalinstructions.html

> Place all the sources and **patches** in a directory that will be accessible from the chroot environment such as /mnt/lfs/sources/. Do **not** put sources in /mnt/lfs/tools/.

3 hours in Google, dough...

Comment: Okay, so I at least have that part right. My output seems to be asking for a file to add the patch to, but that isn't referenced anywhere in the guide that I can see. Am I using the incorrect syntax, or am I doing it from the wrong folder, perhaps?  I ran that line from the /mnt/lfs/tools directory, but I'm not sure where I should be that I can reference the file in question with ../ like that.

Comment: This is not appropriate forum, try this one. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lfs

Comment: Aaaaand posted on the site you linked. Thanks!